# How to handle heavy downloads by clients( approximately 150 MB each client ) in IIS and Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

An application runs on On-premise and as well as in azure app service. There are 100s of clients(agents)that required sometimes to download msi file from the Asp.Net core application. There have been times when 100s of clients would reach out try to download file at once and that would overwhelm the website. The file sits in wwwroot of Asp.Net core folder. The goal is to limit clients from downloading file at once. May be 10 clients at a time. The solution should be optimal for IIS On-Premise and Azure.

Comment: Use a CDN? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/cdn/

Comment: I think you can try to Optimizing IIS Performance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/optimizing-iis-performance